# want to stop restarting asynctask on orientation change

Tags: android

My application simply request the `json` data from `url` and displays it in `TableLayout`. I used `asynctask` to request the `json` data and then I use that `json`data to fill my `TableLayout`. It works correct but on change of device orientation it again request the `json` data by running `AsyncTask`. I just want to stop calling `AsyncTask` again.i want the `AsyncTask` to run only once during lifetime of `activity`.

Comment: add  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" to the activity in manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` in your activity that prevents the restart activity when orientation change.

Comment: hey thanks yar. but i dont understand the problem coz i had done the same thing in other app but it works fine but in this app it creates problem

Comment: @KailashDabhi  Problem is nothing but when you change orientation activity restart again . so it called everything .

Answer (score 2):

To keep the AsyncTask running your should override [onRetainNonConfigurationChange()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) (or [setRetainInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29), but note it is API11!) and pass your AsyncTask there to keep it alive. Alternatively, you can tell framework your activity will deal with some configuration changes by itself, by adding

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

to your `<activity>`. But this is not correct approach (rather a shortcut) as you want just task retained not everything else.

Comment: onRetainNonConfigurationInstance () Method is depriciated.

Comment: Sure it is, but I linked to `onRetainNonConfigurationChange()` on purpose, as we do not know what SDK OP targets (`setRetainInstance()` is API 11), so that's way he can find out about both. Edited anyway